# Enforcing iOS App transport security

Tags: ios, iphone, http, alamofire

From iOS 9 and above, Apple has enforced users to make HTTPS Requests with Specific Host for Security Purpose, or if HTTP request must be made, Apple expects users to provide and exception in the plist about the same.

Something like:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>api.themoviedb.org</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

However, if I remove this code from the plist, and run my code on the device (iOS 11), it still CORRECTLY loads the HTTP requests, without any warnings whatsoever.

The question is, if Apple has enforced the use of HTTPS, why am I able to make HTTP calls without any warnings ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is not according to a recent twitter conversation by @KrauseFX
https://twitter.com/KrauseFx/status/942741438890233856

Thought I'd share

Comment: Well, looks like they enforced this, something broke, then they decided to revert back the enforcement rule (as per https://twitter.com/Javi/status/942805306781810688).
Thanks.